# Set org babel results section to folded

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Is it possible to set `#+RESULTS` section for specific source blocks to folded? Just like you would add visibility folded property to a heading.

Answer (score 1):

`TAB` (bound to `org-cycle`) will fold `#+RESULTS` interactively.

From lisp, you can use the functions `org-babel-hide-result-toggle-maybe`, `org-babel-hide-result-toggle`, `org-babel-result-hide-all` to hide results. The toggles are idempotent, so another call will show the results. The inverse of the last is `org-babel-result-show-all`. Check their docstrings for details.

I don't think there is a way to control that out of the box using properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have indicated in the questions that I was aware of these options. It's a pity that there is no visibility option for this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a workaround. I am fairly happy with it. I use named source blocks anyway, so one can use the results block name to fold it on file opening.

```
(defun ib//org-babel-fold-named-results (block-names)
  ""
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (name block-names)
      (org-babel-goto-named-result name)
      (end-of-line)
      (if (not (overlays-at (point)))
          (org-babel-hide-result-toggle)))))
```

For example, the following folds a source block called "test" in the org file.

```
#+name: test
#+begin_src python
print(3.)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: test
: 3.0

# Local Variables:
# eval: (ib//org-babel-fold-named-results '("test"))
# End:
```